# Обособление сравнительных оборотов

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, как, сравнительный-оборот

Почему используются разные правила обособления оборотов с союзом КАК  в следующих предложениях:

(1) В гневе он как гром загремел, как сталь засверкал.

(2) Лёд, как сталь, засверкал в холодных лучах осеннего солнца.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Для предложения (1) действует правило: Оборот с союзом КАК не обособляется, если на первый план выступает значение обстоятельства образа действия (вопрос как?); обычно такие обороты можно заменить Т.п. существительного, например: В гневе он как гром (громом) загремел, как сталь (сталью)  засверкал.

Но почему это правило не применяются для предложения (2)?

Comment: Тат, там комментарии закончились. Пишу, поэтому, здесь. Кто автор этих книг? И есть ли они в интернете?

Comment: Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник по пунктуации. - М., АСТ, 1997. 
http://eknigi.org/gumanitarnye_nauki/153622-spravochnik-po-punktuacii.html

Былинский К. И., Розенталь Д. Э. Трудные случаи пунктуации. – М., 1959. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/n71oq0jd01vr2gg/%D0%91%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C.%20%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8.pdf

Comment: Спасибо, Тат!

Comment: @tat Ссылка на "Трудные случаи пунктуации" не работает. Сохранился ли у вас файл?

Comment: Выложила книгу сюда: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19Dm4Rj_hL8qA2368XQJ6CcZeBw5qTYll

Comment: @tat Спасибо огромное! Оповещение не пришло. Только сейчас прочитал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Розенталь объяснял так: в некоторых случаях, особенно в произведениях художественной литературы, ставятся запятые, чтобы подчеркнуть значение образа, создаваемого путем сравнения.

*Гляжу, как безумный, на черную шаль..*. (Пушкин) (значение *подобно безумцу* преобладает над значением *гляжу безумцем*).

*Она ускользнет, как змея, порхнет и умчится, как птичка* (Лермонтов) (хотя можно сказать *ускользнет змеей, умчится птичкой*).

Comment: Но предложение "В гневе он как гром загремел, как сталь засверкал" тоже из художественной литературы, в нем много экспрессии, поэтому тоже очень хочется подчеркнуть образность сравнения. Но мы её почему-то не подчеркиваем. И вообще такое решение вряд ли может служить руководством к действию - скорее, Розенталь выразил свое интуитивное понимание проблемы. А как быть школьникам, которые должны правильно написать и правильно объяснить.

Comment: София, вы правы: экспрессия есть. Но в вашем случае скорее всего преобладает значение отожествления или приравнивания.

Comment: Вот еще из Розенталя: При анализе подобных примеров мы исходим из авторской пунктуации и пытаемся ее объяснить, что, как известно, является делом весьма сложным. Так, мы можем допустить, что в предложении "Она ускользнёт, как змея, порхнёт и умчится, как птичка" автору важно было создать художественные образы путем, так сказать, чистого сравнения (подобно змее, подобно птичке, хотя сравнение сохраняется и в сочетаниях ускользнёт змеёй, умчится птичкой, но с добавочным оттенком образа действия).

Comment: Это вопрос гибкой, авторской пунктуации. Школьникам такие примеры лучше давать на факультативах, когда усвоены азы.

Comment: Тат, а в предложение: Он(,) как гром гремел . Вы запятую поставите?

Comment: Да, Тат, это правило у Розенталя я помню.

Comment: Такие предложения допускают двоякую пунктуацию. Если он гремел так, как гремит гром, напоминая гром, - "он, как гром, гремел". Если он гремел очень громко, громообразно, громом гремел - "он как гром гремел".

Comment: Плохо, что в правилах такие нюансы не учитываются. Приходится самому догадываться.

Comment: Розенталь сформулировал правила, потом написал к ним примечания, а потом примечания к примечаниям... И так появилась книга "Трудные случаи пунктуации".

Comment: К сожалению, из громоздкой ссылки, не могу ее здесь представить.Это сайт Видеотьютор по русскому языку.

Comment: Tat, а если я перестрою предложение, то нужно обособлять оборот? Получаем предложение: В гневе он загремел, как гром, засверкал, как сталь.

Answer (score 2):

Второе предложение никак нельзя заменить обстоятельством образа действия, которое  при этом соответствует творительному существительного. Сверкал сталью ? Разве сталью можно сверкать? А вот "сверкал, подобно льду, или: словно лед" - можно. Здесь вне сомнения сравнительное значение, а не обстоятельство образа действия.

Comment: А в первом предложении человек может сверкать сталью? Запятой-то нет.

Comment: Тат, я не понял вы о чем.

Comment: Серж, здесь дело не в наполнении синтаксической конструкции конкретным содержанием, а в структуре этой конструкции. Тем не менее рассмотрим другой, поэтический пример: (1) "Ночь весенней негой дышит, Ветер взморья не колышет, Весь залив блестит, как сталь" (А. Фет). Здесь правильно обособлено? И вот еще пример для сравнения: (2) "Справа, за глубоким, тёмным обрывом, синел, блестя как сталь, залив Чёрного моря". А здесь правильно не обособлено?

Comment: София, в первом предложении -да, запятая нужна, здесь на лицо сравнение.Когда залив блестит, он блестит так, как сталь. Явное сравнение. Во втором предложении выделяется из однородных членов предложения весь оборот: блестя как сталь. И да, здесь правильно не обособлено. Согласно правилам, если  оборот является сказуемым или тесно примыкает к сказуемому (такое сказуемое без оборота лишается смысла). В предложение:  Весь залив блестит, как сталь.

Comment: Если убрать сравнительный оборот , то сказуемое не лишается смысла. Ср.: весь залив блестит. Но: Весь залив блестя ? "Блестя как сталь"- здесь, как вы сами понимаете ,причастный оборот со сравнительным значением. А причастный оборот не мыслится без зависимых от него слов. Поэтому запятая не нужна.

Comment: Ну да, всё правильно, но остается вопрос, по какому правилу различаются варианты "он как сталь засверкал" и  "весь залив блестит, как сталь"? Как классическая орфография их различает?

Comment: Во всех приведенных примерах может быть с запятой и без в зависимости от того, что хотел подчеркнуть автор - образ действия или чистое сравнение с объектом. "Синел, блестя, залив" - вполне допустимо употребить одиночное деепричастие, зависимых слов оно не требует. "Блестя, как сталь" = блестя так, как блестит сталь; "Блестя как сталь" = блестя сталью, блестя стальным блеском.
Правда, есть еще одно соображение. "Синел, блестя как сталь, залив" - тут запятая не нужна, потому что создает двусмысленность: "синел, ..., как сталь, залив".

Comment: Он как сталь засверкал. В правилах говорится, что это обстоятельство образа действия.

Comment: Запятая убирается, чтобы показать отнесенность сравнения к деепричастию.  Ср.: "Я мчался на лихом коне, как ветер волен и один" — не «мчался, как ветер», а «волен и один, как ветер».

Comment: Серж, в каких правилах говорится? В упрощенных школьных? Мы уже обсуждаем вопросы высшего пилотажа, из книги "Трудные случаи пунктуации".